# Запуск нескольких php-скриптов одновременно с помощью shell/bash

Tags: php, ubuntu, bash, shell, cron

Имеется сервер Ubuntu на котором крутятся сайты.
необходимо одновременно запускать php-скрипты каждые 10 минут:

```
php /home/admin/1.php
php /home/admin/2.php
...
php /home/admin/10.php
```

Каждый скрипт работает продолжительное время. 
Каким образом можно создать sh-скрипт (который будет запускаться Cron-ом каждые 10 минут), в котором предыдущий список php-файлов будет запускаться одновременно, а не поочередно?

Создать под каждый php-скрипт отдельную Cron-задачу не предлагать.

Comment: `&` после команд в sh-скрипте дописывайте

Answer (score 3):

чтобы отправить процесс, запускаемый командой, в фон, в конце команды используйте разделитель команд `&` (вместо разделителя `;`, эквивалентного символу новой строки).

т.е., вместо:

```
команда1
команда2
команда3
```

или эквивалентной записи в одну строку:

```
команда1 ; команда2 ; команда3
```

используйте:

```
команда1 &
команда2 &
команда3
```

или эквивалентную запись в одну строку:

```
команда1 & команда2 & команда3
```

тогда процессы, запускаемые `командой1` и `командой2` будут отправлены в фон.

---

p.s. да, можно и процесс, запускаемый последней командой, тоже отправить в фон, добавив `&` после `команда3`